# $.animate() jQuery display:table without affecting unspecified spatial dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-tables

When using jQuery's `$.animate()` on a `display:table`, spatial dimensions not specified to change will animate.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8afB/)

In this case, `width` is specified, but `height` isn't, yet `height` jumps around.  In this case, how can a `display:table`'s `height` be kept from visually changing?

**html**

```
<div style="display:table; height:40px;">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div class="cell">
            Short text
        </div>
        <div class="cell cellToAnimate">
            Really long text
        </div>
        <div class="cell cellToAnimate">
            Really, really, really long text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" id="cellChanger">Change cells</button>
```

**css**

```
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**js**

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('.cellToAnimate').hide();

$("#cellChanger").click(function(){
    $('.cellToAnimate').stop(true,false).animate({
        width: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    });
});
```

});

Comment: I have encountered something similar to this before, and found nothing that I could do. I believe it is because the animation converts the display to `block` while animating, and so if you have any display styles which depend on the current display, they will be altered during the animation.

Comment: @TravisJ exactly the wrong thing i wanted to hear :/  have you had any luck with a containing `div` with specified `height`, `max-height`?

Comment: Sorry :( Maybe others have had more luck with it than I have. In my case it was for an accordian, and some of the text jumped. I ended up just having to change the design for that area to accommodate a constant `display:block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

style a container with

```
display: block;
height: 40px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: +1 This works for this situation. **[Here is a fiddle demo for it](http://jsfiddle.net/X8afB/3/)**

Comment: @Gracchus - That is actually what he meant, I just made a demo of it and the only change I made was his suggestion. In fact, using `overflow:hidden` is the magic here. It worked for the situation I mentioned above in comments. Very nice answer, I wouldn't want to detract from it by placing a competing one.

Comment: @Gracchus - I think some improvement would be fine. Although the answer is short, the approach actually worked so I think that deserves credit.